# Why is the plot of bump function in two variables asymmetric?

Tags: functions, vectors, exponential-function, fourier-transform

I am interested in a function:
$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)$$
on $(-1,1)$ and $0$ otherwise.
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) this function is called bump function. In one variable it is a "bump". On the right side of the wikipedia page there is a [plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#/media/File:Bump2D_illustration.png) of the bump function in two variables. It looks like croissant. I tried to plot
$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}\right)$$
in Wolfram alpha. It has circular symmetry. There is no croissant. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Wikipedia picture illustrates **a** bump function, not "**the** bump function" that you have plotted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bump function $f(x,y)$, defined on $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$
$$
f(x,y) = \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}\right)}
$$
and $f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise has radial symmetry.

To show it go in polar coordinates:
$$
\begin{align}
x &= r \cos(\theta) \\
y &= r \sin(\theta) 
\end{align}
$$

and observe that $r^2=x^2+y^2$ is the equation of a circle. So you get
$$
f(r) = \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{1-r^2}\right)}
$$
so $f$ depends only by radius ($r$) and not angle.

The picture you refering to represents a bump function (it is smooth, compactly supported and not analytic) but it is not $f(x,y)$.